# Как задать синхронное исполнение кода в функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, alert

У меня есть код который должен исполняться по истечению времени:

```js
TheEndSound();
confirm('TIME IS RUNNING OUT');
```

```js
//--- Запускает звуковую дорожку ---
function TheEndSound() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../sound/sound.mp3";
    audio.autoplay = true;
}
```

Желаемый результат: (1) начал исполнятся звук (2) вывод alert'a
Результат: (1) вывод alert'a (2) начал исполнятся звук

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо повеситься на [какой-либо евент](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events). попробуйте [этот, например](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp):

```
function TheEndSound() {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "../sound/sound.mp3";
    audio.autoplay = true;
    audio.onplay = () => confirm('TIME IS RUNNING OUT');
}
```

Comment: Помогло, только теперь когда появляеться confirm, то звук останавливаеться... и продолжаеться только когда закроеться окно

Comment: @KobetsMatviy Это нормальное поведение для модальных окон (alert, confirm, prompt итп). Они прерывают выполнение всего на странице, до того момента, как пользователь не отреагирует. Пользуйтесь `console.log` или заверстайте себе свой, не модальный алерт